# How to connect to X app via VNC which was by xvfb-run?

Tags: linux, x11, display, xvfb, x11vnc

When I run `Xvfb` server directly, `x11vnc` can attach to the display fine as per [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb#Remote_control_over_SSH).

However I'd like to achieve the same by running the X app using `xvfb-run`.

Here is my attempt (to run `wine explorer` as an example):

```
$ xvfb-run -l --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" wine explorer
$ ps x | grep Xvfb
19536 pts/2    Sl     0:00 Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -auth /tmp/xvfb-run.nJKLnF/Xauthority
```

However when I'm trying to run `x11vnc` it fails:

```
$ x11vnc -display :99.0 -usepw -forever -autoport 5900
24/11/2016 22:51:29 XOpenDisplay(":99.0") failed.
24/11/2016 22:51:29 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified

24/11/2016 22:51:29 ***************************************
24/11/2016 22:51:29 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:99.0)

*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":99.0", it cannot continue.
*** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
```

I also tried the command suggested from [x11vnc troubleshooting page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x11vnc#Troubleshooting), but with no luck.

How can I run X command via `xvfb-run` so it display can be accessible by `x11vnc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in your `ps` output, the `Xvfb` server is run with parameter `-auth` followed by the name of a temporary file. To connect to this server you therefore need to provide a copy of the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE that is held in this file. 
Usually this is done by simply setting the XAUTHORITY variable in the environment of the command, eg

```
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xvfb-run.nJKLnF/Xauthority x11vnc ...
```

To simplify, your `xvfb-run` script might accept an option `-f` followed by the name of a file of your choice in which to save the cookie.